# Polymer dom-repeat does not update the items array when a selection made in paper-swatch-picker

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am using `paper-swatch-picker` for picking a color and a `dom-repeat` to iterate over an Array.
when I select color, it does not update in the Array.
Can somebody help me propagating swatch picker `color` change to Array.

I can add multiple rows, each row with 3 color picker (foreground, background and border).
What I want is to have my Array `decoratorList` updated when I pick a color.

Below is the codepen for reference.
http://codepen.io/khanshahid/pen/wzGrxk

```html
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
  
  <link rel="import" href="iron-input/iron-input.html"> 
  <link rel="import" href="iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html"> 
  <link rel="import" href="paper-material/paper-material.html"> 
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html"> 
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input-container.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html"> 
  <link rel="import" href="paper-toast/paper-toast.html"> 
  <link rel="import" href="paper-fab/paper-fab.html"> 
  <link rel="import" href="paper-swatch-picker/paper-swatch-picker.html"> 
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:1200px;">
   <msk-decorator 
        tag-id= 1
        color-list='["#65a5f2", "#83be54", "#f0d551", "#e5943c", "#a96ddb","#aabbcc","#aaa","#ccc","#eee","#333", "transparent", "none"]'
        data-type="Enum">
    </msk-decorator>
  </div>
  
  <dom-module id="msk-decorator">
  <template>
    <style is="custom-style">
      :host{
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
      };
      .flex-horizontal-with-ratios {
        @apply(--layout-horizontal);
      }
      .flexchild {
        @apply(--layout-flex);
      }
      .flex2child {
        @apply(--layout-flex-2);
      }
      
      .flex-equal-justified {
        @apply(--layout-horizontal);
        @apply(--layout-justified);
      }
      .decorator-container{
        margin: 15px 5px 15px 5px;
        min-height: 160px;
        max-height: 240px;
      }
      .decorator-main{
        padding-top: 10px;
        min-height: 120px;
        max-height: 240px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }
      .decorator-heading-text{
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding-right: 5px;
      }
      .button-add-decorator{
        color: #000;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
        margin-left: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      }
      .deco-buttons{
        float: right; 
        margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
      }
      .deco-button{
        color: #000;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
        box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      }
      
      button:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
      }
      input, select, textarea, .text, .password{
        background: #fff;
        
      }
      input:hover, input:active, input:focus, select:hover, select:active, select:focus, textarea:hover,textarea:focus  {
        border-color: transparent;
        box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      }
      input[disabled], select[disabled]{
        color: #a2a2a2;
        background-color: #e1e2e5;
      }
      .deco-dropdown{
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-right: 10px; 
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      .fa .fa-save {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
      }
      .label-align{
        padding-right: 3px;
      }
      .deco-row{
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid #c3c3c3;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="decorator-container">
      <div class="flex-equal-justified decorator-heading-section">
        <span class="decorator-heading-text">Decorators 
          <button class="button-add-decorator" on-tap="addNewDecorator" >+</button>
        </span>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{saveFlag}}">
          <div class="deco-buttons" style="color: #000;">
            <button class="deco-button" on-tap="saveDecorators">Save</button>
          </div>          
        </template>
      </div> 
      <div class="decorator-main">
        <form id="decoratorForm">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{decoratorList}}">
            <div class="flex-horizontal-with-ratios deco-row">
              <div class="flex2child" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                <span>Text color </span>
                <paper-swatch-picker id="textColor" column-count=5 color-list='[[colorList]]' color=[[item.textColor]] noink ></paper-swatch-picker>
              </div>              
              <div class="flex2child">
                <span>Cell color </span>
                <paper-swatch-picker id="cellColor" column-count=5 color-list='[[colorList]]' color=[[item.cellColor]] noink ></paper-swatch-picker>
              </div>
              <div class="flex2child">
                <span>Border color </span>
                <paper-swatch-picker id="borderColor" color=[[item.borderColor]] noink ></paper-swatch-picker>
              </div>
                
                <div class="" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-right: 4px;">
                   <button class="button-add-decorator" on-tap="removeDecorator" id="[[index]]">X</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </form>
      </div>      
  </template>
    </div>    
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'msk-decorator',
      properties: {
        selectedColor: {
          type: String,
          value: '#E91E63',
          notify: true
        },
        decoratorList: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true,
          value: []
        },
        decoratorObject: {
          type: Object,
          value: {
            textColor: '',
            cellColor: '',
            borderColor: ''
          }
        },
        dataType: {
          type: String,
          notify: true
        },
        tagId: {
          type: String,
          notify: true
        },
        requestObj: {
          type: Object,
          value: {
            id: null,
            addDecorator: [],
            editDecorator: [],
            deleteDecorator: []
          }
        },
        saveFlag: {
          type: Boolean,
          notify: true
        },
        colorList: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true
        },
        dataURL:{
          type: String,
          value: function (){
            var url = '/api/FindDecorators';
            return url; 
          }
        }
      },
      ready: function () {
        this.init();
      },
      attached: function() {
        
      },
      typeChanged: function(e) {
        console.log("typeChanged", e);
      },
      init: function(){        
        this.decoratorObject = {
          textColor:    '#000000',
          cellColor:    '#000000',
          borderColor:  '#000000'
        };
        this.format = [{ 
            id: "9999",
            label: "9999"
          },
          {
            id: "9999.9",
            label: "9999.9"
          },
          {
            id: "9999.99",
            label: "9999.99"
          },
          {
            id: "9999.999",
            label: "9999.999"
          }];
        this.type = [{
            id: "NE",
            label: "NOT EQUAL"
          },
          {
            id: "E",
            label: "EQUAL"
        }];
        this.value = [{
            id: "1",
            label: "Running"
          },
          {
            id: "0",
            label: "Stopped"
        }];
      },
      addNewDecorator: function(e){
        this.push('decoratorList', this.decoratorObject);
        this.saveFlag = true;
      },
      removeDecorator: function(e){
        if(e.target.decoratorId > 0){
          this.push('deletedDecoratorList',e.target.decoratorId);  
        }
        var i = Polymer.dom(e).rootTarget.id;
        this.splice('decoratorList', i, 1);
        this.saveFlag = true;
      },
      showFormat: function(dataTypeValue){
        if(dataTypeValue.indexOf('Enum') > -1)
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      },
      isIdExists: function(tagId){
        if(tagId){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
      },
      displaySave: function(){
        if(this.saveFlag){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
      },
      handleResponse: function(res, ele){
        this.decoratorList = [];
        if(this.decoratorList.length > 0){
          this.saveFlag = true;
        }else{
          this.saveFlag = false;
        }
      },
      saveDecorators: function(){
        console.log('saveDecorators' + this.decoratorList);
        for(var i=0; i < this.decoratorList.length; i++){
         console.log(this.decoratorList[i]);            
        }
    }

      });
  </script>
</dom-module>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `value-changed` event which will return a `CustomEvent` wich has the changed element in it:

```js
attached: function() {
    let pickers = this.$.decoratorForm.querySelectorAll('paper-swatch-picker');
    pickers.forEeach(el => el.addEventListener('value-changed', event => {
        // Do the Array manipulation here based on the event.detail.item
    });
}

// also remove the event listener in detached(), but for that you need
// to define the function elsewhere and just passing it's reference to
// the addEventListener.
```

Then you can make the `this.decoratorList` manipulation, thats will be synchronized with the `{{decoratorList}}` data binding.

> **NOTE:** The `value-changed` event is fired when a `notify: true` property changed, so it may fired multiple times if an internal event changing multiple properties in an element.